# simple CATextLayer scaling problem

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I'm having a simple scaling problem with CATextLayer, but i just couldn't figure it out:
I want the CATextLayer to proportionally grow in size with it's superlayer:
if the superlayer's width is 300 the text size of CATextLayer should be 12 and if the supeview's width is 600 the text size should be 24.
I couldn't find a working solution!

Can you please give me a clue?

Thanks, Julian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale the font size proportionately. For example, if the superlayer's width changes from 300 to 600, that's 600/300 = 2. Then multiply the font size by 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the layer to scale with its superlayer, you need to set its `autoresizingMask` property like so:

```
myTextLayer.autoresizingMask = ( kCALayerWidthSizable | kCALayerHeightSizable );
```

However, this probably won't change the size of the text as that's a fixed property of `CATextLayer`. You will probably have to change the size of the text in response to a change in the size of the layer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
You should -

```
 [textLayer setContentsScale:theScaleOfSuperLayer];
```